# how convert cell(with data separate with comma) in column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data like this:

```
 1245   S,M,L
 1356   S,M,L,XL
```

What is the easy way for make this:

```
1245    S
1245    M
1245    L
1356    S
1356    M
1356    L
1356    XL
```

Comment: What did you already try? At which point in that did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm very newbie in excel i have no idea

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably easiest to solve using VBA (imo). Here's a really simple solution that will get you started. You'll probably need to change where you want to output the data.

```
Sub sizeSplitter()

Dim IDs As Range
    Set IDs = Selection 'Select your range of IDs

Dim rowCounter As Integer
    rowCounter = 2

For Each subRange In IDs

    Dim Sizes() As String

    Sizes = Split(subRange.Offset(0, 1).Value, ",")

    For i = LBound(Sizes) To UBound(Sizes)

        Cells(rowCounter, 4) = subRange.Value
        Cells(rowCounter, 5) = Sizes(i)

        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1

    Next

Next subRange

End Sub
```

Ending data looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKZYq.png).

To use, highlight the IDs you want to do this to. Also, it's highly advised to move any data you have in columns D and E out of the way, unless you want it getting written over :)